# Find cyclic links in excel using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have a table as follows. This indicates links (or edges) between values in the `Name`column.

```
+-------+-------------------+
| Name  | from              |
+-------+-------------------+
| G     | X; Y; HG; WP      |
| X     | U                 |
| Y     |                   |
| U     | V                 |
| V     |                   |
| K     | M; N              |
| M     |                   |
| N     |                   |
| G1    | G                 |
| G2    | G1                |
| G3    | G2                |
| G4a   | G3                |
| J     | G4a               |
| G4b   | G3                |
| G5b   | G4b               |
| H     | G5b               |
| R     | H; J              |
| R1    | R                 |
| R2    | R1                |
| O     | R2                |
| O1    | O                 |
| O2    | O1                |
| O3    | O2                |
| F     | H; K; TR          |
| P     | G; Z              |
| Z     |                   |
| HG    | VB; NH            |
| WP    |                   |
| TR    | Z                 |
| VB    | ICH; OL; NZ; LO   |
| NH    |                   |
| ICH   | NZ                |
| NZ    |                   |
| LO    |                   |
| OL    | TZ; HG            |
| TZ    |                   |
| BN    | WD; PO            |
| WD    | RZ; UX            |
| PO    | QA; IU; BV; MM; BN|
| RZ    |                   |
| UX    |                   |
| IU    |                   |
| QA    |                   |
| BV    |                   |
| MM    |                   |
+-------+-------------------+
```

I want to see if values in `Name`column exist as predecessors if we sequentially look up values in `from`column. In other words I want to see if there are any cyclic links.

How to do this with `VBA` code in excel?

In this example `HG, VB, OL, BN, PO` have cyclic links. I want to highlight only those cells in column "Name".

One way is to find all predecessors for each row in a separate column as follows.

```
+-------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GName | from               | predecessors                                                                                                                                        |
+-------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| G     | X; Y; HG; WP       | X; U; V; Y; HG; VB; NH; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ; WP                                                                                                     |
| X     | U                  | U; V                                                                                                                                                |
| Y     |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| U     | V                  | V                                                                                                                                                   |
| V     |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| K     | M; N               | M; N                                                                                                                                                |
| M     |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| N     |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| G1    | G                  | G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                                                  |
| G2    | G1                 | G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                                              |
| G3    | G2                 | G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                                          |
| G4a   | G3                 | G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                                      |
| J     | G4a                | G4a; G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                                 |
| G4b   | G3                 | G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                                      |
| G5b   | G4b                | G4b; G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                                 |
| H     | G5b                | G5b; G4b; G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                                            |
| R     | H; J               | J; G4a; G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ; H; G5b; G4b; G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ |
| R1    | R                  | R; J; H; G4a; G5b; G3; G4b; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                              |
| R2    | R1                 | R1; R; J; H; G4a; G5b; G3; G4b; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                          |
| O     | R2                 | R2; R1; R; J; H; G4a; G5b; G3; G4b; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                      |
| O1    | O                  | O; R2; R1; R; J; H; G4a; G5b; G3; G4b; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                                   |
| O2    | O1                 | O1; O; R2; R1; R; J; H; G4a; G5b; G3; G4b; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                               |
| O3    | O2                 | O2; O1; O; R2; R1; R; J; H; G4a; G5b; G3; G4b; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ                                           |
| F     | H; KTR             | K; M; N; H; G5b; G4b; G3; G2; G1; G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ; TR; Z                                                         |
| P     | G; Z               | G; X; Y; HG; WP; U; VB; NH; V; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ; Z                                                                                               |
| Z     |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| HG    | VB; NH             | VB; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; HG; TZ; NH; NH                                                                                                                 |
| WP    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| TR    | Z                  | Z                                                                                                                                                   |
| VB    | ICH; OL; NZ; LO    | ICH; NZ; NZ; LO; OL; HG; TZ; VB; NH; ICH; NZ; LO                                                                                                    |
| NH    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| ICH   | NZ                 | NZ                                                                                                                                                  |
| NZ    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| LO    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| OL    | TZ; HG             | HG; VB; NH; ICH; NZ; LO; OL; TZ; TZ                                                                                                                 |
| TZ    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| BN    | WD; PO             | WD; RZ; UX; PO; BN; IU; QA; BV; MM; WD; RZ; UX                                                                                                      |
| WD    | RZ; UX             | RZ; UX                                                                                                                                              |
| PO    | QA; IU; BV; MM; BN | BN; WD; PO; RZ; UX; IU; QA; BV; MM; IU; QA; BV; MM                                                                                                  |
| RZ    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| UX    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| IU    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| QA    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| BV    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
| MM    |                    |                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now a search for values in `Name` column in the corresponding cell in the `predecessors` column will give the desired result.

How to achieve this using `VBA` code in excel?

**EDIT** As I understand this is a network problem. Here is the network diagram for more clarity.

[image]

**EDIT2** Here is my attempt (VBA noob here) in the direction suggested by **@GSerg**. Stuck at fetching locations of predecessors. Getting `Argument not optional` error.

```
Public Function NetworkCyclicityCheck(node As String, col As Range) As String

Dim dicP As Object: Set dicP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

If Trim(node) <> "" Then
        For Each x In Split(cl.Value2, ";")
            Key = Trim(x)
            With Range
            pcell = .Find(What:=Key, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
            dicP(pcell) = dicP(pcell) & "," & cl.Address(0, 0)
        Next x
End If

Set NetworkCyclicityCheck = dicP
Set dicP = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand clearly the logic behind this process. So `HG` is cyclic because values `VB` and `NH` appear in column `Name`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns `HG` is cyclic as it appears as the predecessor of `VB`. The sequential link is `HG <- VB <- OL <- HG`.

Comment: Because I am lazy, I would assign a cell to each of the nodes, and entered `=A+B+C...` into that cell, where the summands are the cells I assigned to the nodes that are predecessors of this cell. Then Excel would figure it out and I would read it back from [`Worksheet.CircularReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.circularreference)

Comment: @GSerg Entering cells assigned to predecessors for each cell would be difficult as the real dataset in which I am trying to check for cyclicity has over 5000 rows. So the lazy solution in this case is would be a code based one. :-)

Comment: So being lazy that I am, I would write some very simple code to assign 5000 consecutive cell addresses to the 5000 rows, and generate the formulas...

Comment: @GSerg please check out my attempt to get the formulas.

Comment: @Crops That code is invalid on several levels and I'm not sure what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem odd to some, but this question really intrigued me given I'd never come across a situation where I've needed to write recursive code before.

Not sure how efficient it is, but it works instantly in my limited testing. Drop this into a new module and it should run just fine.

```
Option Explicit

Private DestinationByLocation As Object

Sub Test()

  HighlightTheCycles Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B46"), , True, True

End Sub

Public Sub HighlightTheCycles(ByVal TableRange As Range, Optional ClearExistingFill As Boolean = True, Optional OutputTheLoopPath As Boolean = False, Optional AlertIfNoCycles As Boolean = False)

  Dim InputData As Variant, OutputRange As Range
  Dim x As Long, y As Long, Temp As Variant

  Dim LoopLocations As Object
  Set DestinationByLocation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set LoopLocations = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  DestinationByLocation.CompareMode = 1
  LoopLocations.CompareMode = 1

'Set fill to 'no-fill'
  If ClearExistingFill Then
    If OutputTheLoopPath Then
      TableRange.Resize(TableRange.Rows.Count, 3).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Else
      TableRange.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
  End If

'Establish all possible destinations
  InputData = TableRange.Value
  For x = 1 To UBound(InputData, 1)
    If Len(InputData(x, 2)) > 0 Then
      Temp = Split(InputData(x, 2), ";")
      For y = 0 To UBound(Temp, 1)
        Temp(y) = Trim(Temp(y))
        If DestinationByLocation.Exists(Temp(y)) Then
          DestinationByLocation(Temp(y)) = DestinationByLocation(Temp(y)) & ";" & InputData(x, 1)
        Else
          DestinationByLocation.Add Temp(y), InputData(x, 1)
        End If
      Next y
    End If
  Next x

'Look for loops
  Dim TempPath As Variant
  Temp = DestinationByLocation.Keys
  For x = 1 To UBound(Temp, 1)
    TempPath = TakeATrip(Temp(x))
    If Right(TempPath, 3) = ";;;" Then
      TempPath = Split(Left(TempPath, Len(TempPath) - 3), ";")
      If TempPath(UBound(TempPath, 1)) = Temp(x) Then
        LoopLocations.Add Temp(x), TempPath
      End If
    End If
  Next x

'Mark the cells that result in a loop
  If LoopLocations.Count > 0 Then
    If OutputTheLoopPath Then

      'Output the loop path found in a third column
      ReDim Temp(1 To UBound(InputData, 1), 1 To 1)
      For x = 1 To UBound(InputData, 1)
        If LoopLocations.Exists(InputData(x, 1)) Then
          If OutputRange Is Nothing Then
            Set OutputRange = TableRange.Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 3)
          Else
            Set OutputRange = Union(OutputRange, TableRange.Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 3))
          End If
          Temp(x, 1) = Join(LoopLocations(InputData(x, 1)), ";")
          Temp(x, 1) = Replace(Right(Temp(x, 1), Len(Temp(x, 1)) - 1), ";", " ;")
        End If
      Next x
      TableRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 2).Resize(UBound(Temp, 1), 1).Value = Temp

    Else

      'Do not output a third column
      For x = 1 To UBound(InputData, 1)
        If LoopLocations.Exists(InputData(x, 1)) Then
          If OutputRange Is Nothing Then
            Set OutputRange = TableRange.Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 2)
          Else
            Set OutputRange = Union(OutputRange, TableRange.Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 2))
          End If
        End If
      Next x

    End If

    OutputRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

  ElseIf AlertIfNoCycles Then

    MsgBox _
      "No cycles found in " & TableRange.Address(0, 0, , True), _
      vbInformation

  End If

End Sub

Private Function TakeATrip(ByVal MyLocation As Variant, Optional ExistingPath As Variant = "") As Variant

  Dim MyJourneys As Variant, x As Long
  Dim MyPaths As Variant

'If no new destinations, record the trip
  If DestinationByLocation.Exists(MyLocation) Then
    If DestinationByLocation(MyLocation) = "" Then
      TakeATrip = ExistingPath & ";" & MyLocation
      Exit Function
    End If
  Else
    TakeATrip = ExistingPath & ";" & MyLocation
    Exit Function
  End If

'Prepare for multiple routes
  MyJourneys = Split(DestinationByLocation(MyLocation), ";")
  ReDim MyPaths(0 To UBound(MyJourneys))

  For x = 0 To UBound(MyJourneys)
    If Len(MyJourneys(x)) > 0 Then
      If ExistingPath & ";" & MyLocation Like "*;" & MyJourneys(x) & ";*" Then
        TakeATrip = ExistingPath & ";" & MyLocation & ";" & MyJourneys(x) & ";;;"
        Exit Function 'a loop is found, we're done
      End If
      'explore new found path
      MyPaths(x) = TakeATrip(MyJourneys(x), ExistingPath & ";" & MyLocation)
    End If
    If Right(MyPaths(x), 3) = ";;;" Then
      TakeATrip = MyPaths(x)
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next x

  TakeATrip = Join(MyPaths, "|")

End Function
```

**PLEASE NOTE** Dictionaries are case-sensitive by default. If you need this code to disregard case, add to your declarations at the top:

```
option compare text
```

and change this

```
  Set DestinationByLocation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set LoopLocations = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

to this

```
  Set DestinationByLocation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set LoopLocations = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  DestinationByLocation.CompareMode = 1
  LoopLocations.CompareMode = 1
```

*Thanks to Crops for identifying a bug when no loops found; I corrected the code to include a check for no loops and an optional message box output.*

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58820806/find-cyclic-links-in-excel-using-vba-code?noredirect=1#comment103920952_58820806),

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateFormulas()
  Dim NodeNames As Range
  Set NodeNames = Range("A2:A56")

  ' Assumed that the "from" column is immediately to the right,
  ' and that the column after it is the one where the formulas will appear

  Dim dict As Object
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In NodeNames.Cells
    dict(c.value) = c.Offset(0, 2).Address(False, False, xlA1)
  Next

  For Each c In NodeNames.Cells
    c.Offset(0, 2).Formula = ListToFormula(dict, c.Offset(0, 1).value)
  Next
End Sub

Private Function ListToFormula(ByVal dict As Object, ByVal list As String) As String
  Dim nodes() As String
  nodes = Split(list, ";")

  ListToFormula = "="""""

  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(nodes) To UBound(nodes)
    ListToFormula = ListToFormula & " & " & dict(Trim$(nodes(i)))
  Next
End Function
```

Now you can look at [`Worksheet.CircularReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.circularreference), and it will display nicely on the sheet too:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain `ListToFormula = "="""""`line.

Comment: This is not working when the number of semicolon repeated elements in second column is more than 5.

Comment: @Crops *Can you explain `ListToFormula = "="""""`line* - assign the value of `=""` to the variable `ListToFormula`. *not working when the number of semicolon repeated elements in second column is more than 5* - just tried with 8, no problem.